# Support PHP SOAP WebService

Tags: php, soap, xpath

I've been working on integrating reading a WebService written in .NET from PHP. I found the solutions described here but it has not worked for me:

[PHP Parse SOAP XML response from SOAP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530585/php-parse-soap-xml-response-from-soap-client/23530646#23530646)

I will be very grateful for your support.

**EDIT: This code has already corrections thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987598/mathias-m%C3%BCller Mathias Müller**

The code I've worked below I put at your disposal:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$wsdl = 'http://www.wsplaces.com/Xofigo/wsAppXofigo.asmx?WSDL';
$trace = true;
$exceptions = false;

$data = array(
    'IdEdo' => '9'
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
$response = $client->__soapCall("Get_PlacesByEdo", array($data));

echo"<pre>";
print_r($client);
echo"</pre>";
echo"<pre>";
print_r($client->__last_response);
echo"</pre>";

$lastResponse='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><Get_PlacesByEdoResponse xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/"><Get_PlacesByEdoResult><IdEdo/></Get_PlacesByEdoResult></Get_PlacesByEdoResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'; 

 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($lastResponse);
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xml', 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace');
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://www.tempuri.org/');

 $xpath ='/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/a:Get_PlacesByEdoResponse/a:Get_PlacesByEdoResult/a:IdEdo/text()';

 $result = $xml->xpath($xpath);

 if ($result != FALSE && count($result) > 0) {
      echo '{"reference": "' . $result[0] . '", "success":"true"}';
 } else {
      echo '{"error": "si", "success":"false"}';
 }


 ?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have written. What error are you getting? What unexpected behavior has happened because of the above code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the XML input does not contain an element `a:Get_PlacesByEdo`, because the input XML (in a more readable format) looks like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <Get_PlacesByEdoResponse xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/">
         <Get_PlacesByEdoResult>
            <IdEdo/>
         </Get_PlacesByEdoResult>
      </Get_PlacesByEdoResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Perhaps you were trying to find the `IdEdo` element?

```
$xpath = '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/a:Get_PlacesByEdoResponse/a:Get_PlacesByEdoResult/a:IdEdo/text()';-->
```