# How to convert SOAP API response from XML to JSON

Tags: php, json, xml, api, soap

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetCategoriesJsonResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <GetCategoriesJsonResult>[{"code":"0","description":"Sides","storeNumber":"3733"},{"code":"1","description":"Sandwiches","storeNumber":"3733"},</GetCategoriesJsonResult>
        </GetCategoriesJsonResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

That is the result of the API, but I want to convert it like:

```
[
    {
        "code": "0",
        "description": "Sides",
        "storeNumber": "3733"
    },
    {
        "code": "1",
        "description": "Sandwiches",
        "storeNumber": "3733"
    },
]
```

How can I do this? I've tried `json_encode` and `json_decode` but it didn't work for me. I have applied different methods to convert it but it's still showing XML results. Can anyone tell me how I can convert it into JSON?

Comment: Are you trying to convert it from the text into an object? 

OR 

Are you trying to just pretty print the JSON, on separate lines?

Comment: i want to get json response to iterate inside it
how can i do it in php

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good answer on available options to working with xml https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/3266626

I use [FluentDom](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM)

```
$xml = file_get_contents("xml_file.xml");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$json = new \FluentDOM\Serializer\Json\RabbitFish($doc);
$object = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>" . print_r( $object, true) . "</pre>";
echo "<script>console.log({$json})</script>";
```

**Edit:** replaced

```
// PHP Deprecated: Non-static method DOMDocument::loadXML() should not be called statically
$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);
```

with

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
```

Comment: Have you tried the code? `new \FluentDOM\Serializer\Json\RabbitFish($doc)` returns a json object.

Comment: yes but 
<p>Type: Error</p>
<p>Message: Class 'FluentDOM\Serializer\Json\RabbitFish' not found</p>
<p>Filename: /var/www/html/application/views/backend/add_veggies.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 153</p>

Comment: You have to include FluentDom in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution on that link thanks guys for helping 
    using api response in this way helps me alot 
    [How to convert SOAP response to PHP Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777075/how-to-convert-soap-response-to-php-array)

```
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body = $xml->xpath('//sBody')[0];
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE);
```

This code is perfectly done thing into JSON

Answer (score 0):

First parse xml and convert data to array:

```
$xml=(array)simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
$json_output = $xml['GetCategoriesJsonResult'];
```