# SOAP XML to PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

I'm using `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');` when a service is posting xml data to my url. It's giving me an xml string, but I can't figure out how to turn it into a php array. I've tried every solution I can find here on Stack, and it always gives me an empty array. Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<Authentication xmlns="urn:www.blank.com:blank:services:2:0:wsdl">
<username></username>
<password></password>
</Authentication>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<TransferDataString xmlns="urn:www.blank.com:blank:services:2:0:wsdl">
<data>
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;
&lt;AssessmentResult xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:xsd=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15&quot;&gt;
  &lt;ReceiptId idOwner=&quot;Blank&quot;&gt;
    &lt;IdValue name=&quot;ReceiptID&quot;&gt;2461fg453f99-ea45dsg55-448464-85fgd80-e45fg77e5568b7f1&lt;/IdValue&gt;
    &lt;IdValue name=&quot;bID&quot;&gt;1422255467627&lt;/IdValue&gt;
  &lt;/ReceiptId&gt;
  &lt;ClientOrderId idOwner=&quot;BlankPartner&quot; /&gt;
  &lt;Results&gt;
    &lt;Profile&gt;Blank Credits&lt;/Profile&gt;
    &lt;SupportingMaterials&gt;
      &lt;Description&gt;No Forms Needed&lt;/Description&gt;
    &lt;/SupportingMaterials&gt;
    &lt;OverallResult&gt;
      &lt;Description&gt;Initial Eligibility&lt;/Description&gt;
      &lt;Score type=&quot;PotentialBlank1Eligibility&quot;&gt;0&lt;/Score&gt;
      &lt;Score type=&quot;PotentialBlank2Eligibility&quot;&gt;0&lt;/Score&gt;
    &lt;/OverallResult&gt;
    &lt;DetailResult&gt;
      &lt;Score type=&quot;Eligibility&quot;&gt;0&lt;/Score&gt;
    &lt;/DetailResult&gt;
  &lt;/Results&gt;
  &lt;AssessmentStatus&gt;
    &lt;Status&gt;Completed&lt;/Status&gt;
    &lt;Details&gt;No Errors&lt;/Details&gt;
    &lt;StatusDate&gt;2017-12-20T14:31:04.287072-05:00&lt;/StatusDate&gt;
  &lt;/AssessmentStatus&gt;
&lt;/AssessmentResult&gt;
</data>
</TransferDataString>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've replaced some words with "blank" for obscurity.

I've tried the recursive `xml2array()` functions floating about ([here, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42311833/2634948)). Returns empty array.

I've tried: 
`$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);`

Empty array.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I am now getting this string:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AssessmentResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
  <ReceiptId idOwner="Blank">
    <IdValue name="ReceiptID">2461fg453f99-ea45dsg55-448464-85fgd80-e45fg77e5568b7f1</IdValue>
    <IdValue name="bID">1422255467627</IdValue>
  </ReceiptId>
  <ClientOrderId idOwner="BlankPartner" />
  <Results>
    <Profile>Blank Credits</Profile>
    <SupportingMaterials>
      <Description>No Forms Needed</Description>
    </SupportingMaterials>
    <OverallResult>
      <Description>Initial Eligibility</Description>
      <Score type="PotentialBlank1Eligibility">0</Score>
      <Score type="PotentialBlank2Eligibility">0</Score>
    </OverallResult>
    <DetailResult>
      <Score type="Eligibility">0</Score>
    </DetailResult>
  </Results>
  <AssessmentStatus>
    <Status>Completed</Status>
    <Details>No Errors</Details>
    <StatusDate>2017-12-20T14:31:04.287072-05:00</StatusDate>
  </AssessmentStatus>
</AssessmentResult>
```

from this method:

```
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $string);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body = $xml->xpath('//soapBody')[0];
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE); 
$data = $array['TransferDataString']['data'];
var_dump($data);
```

But I cannot figure out how to convert that string to a PHP array.

Comment: Do you try to read the data element or the whole xml document?

Comment: See update in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the inner data elements...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$data = $xml->xpath("//soap:Body");
$innerData = (string)$data[0]->TransferDataString->children("urn:www.blank.com:blank:services:2:0:wsdl")->data;
// Convert data to array
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string(trim($innerData));
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml2), true);
print_r($array);
```

You can then process the data either as XML, or convert it to an array.
The first part extracts the soap:Body and then it manipulates that to get at the final inner content.

Comment: How do I convert the data to an array?

Comment: Updated with conversion.

Comment: Thanks! It was performing the `trim()` that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXml($source);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xpath->registerNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
$xpath->registerNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$xpath->registerNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xpath->registerNamespace("xmlns", "urn:www.blank.com:blank:services:2:0:wsdl");

// Read the data element
$data = $xpath->query('//soap:Body/xmlns:TransferDataString/xmlns:data')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$data = trim($data);
echo $data;
```

Comment: How do I convert the data to an array? That's what I am asking.