# Convert specific XML to PHP Array

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to convert this specific XML file to PHP Array

http://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.cls?soap_method=QueryByName&name=John

The part I want to get is

```
<QueryByName diffgr:id="QueryByName1"msdata:rowOrder="0"><ID>174</ID><Name>Johnson,Brian T.</Name><DOB>1934-11-09</DOB><SSN>751-82-3888</SSN></QueryByName>
```

I tried to use soapResponseToJson(xml)
And

```
    $xmlfile = file_get_contents($path);

//convert xml string into an object
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);

//convert into json
$json  = json_encode($xml);

//convert into associative array
$xmlArr = json_decode($json, true);
```

But keeps not working.

Can you help me please?
Kind regards.

Comment: Are you trying use QueryByName method and get xml by url like http://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.cls?soap_method=QueryByName&name=Johnson%2CBrian+T.?

Comment: Sorry, I dont write the right url. And yes, but it doesn't works :(

Comment: Try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42311833/2015200